# Saving combinations of ids with volume

Tags: database, algorithm, hash, unique, combinations

I am trying to create a system where users can create grocery lists containing products with thier volumes.

**Background.**

---

The application I am designing takes in a grocery list containing the ids of products with thier amount that are being ordered. The grocery list that has been ordered by user A should be available to user B and all other users. Users also get to see the grocery list that has been ordered the most and each grocery list must also contain the amount of each product in this list.

**(possible) Solution.**

---

One solution I could come up with is to generate a unique hash from these lists. Take the id of the product and multiply that with the volume and add each of these values to come up with the hash value for this particular list. Create two tables.

1. Containing the hash value with the amount of times poeple ordered this list.
2. A lookup table using the hash as unique id and containing the actual products with the amount.

This way you can immediatly see the lists that has been ordered the most and you can get the content of this list.

**Problem.**

---

One really big problem is that I am afraid of hash collisions when calculating the hash value of the lists.

Is there any other 'easier' or 'better' way to solve this problem and/or what hashing algorithm should I be using when sticking to my own solution.

**Edit 1.**

---

The suggestions made in the comments could indeed make a viable solution. However there is still something that is bugging me. Say for instance a list exists with two items: item A with volume 2 and item B with volume 3. Some people use this list to order immediatly while others prefer making their own lists. With this solutiuon there is no easy and fast way to discover if a new list has already been submitted by someone else before. Before saving the list I'd have to check with every existing list if the volume and items match before either updating the existing list or adding a new one.

Would this matter query-wise for a database that contains about 50.000 to 100.000 lists or am I creating problems that don't exists for this scenario?

Comment: Maybe you have a reason you haven't made us aware of, but is there a reason for the hash? Why not just have a table `lists` with a unique, auto-incriment primary key `list_id` that foreign keys to a `list_items` table that contains all the grocery items associated with that list. Then you can have a `customer_lists` xref table where `customer_id` and `list_id` associate the items together. This way a customer can have multiple lists and everything is relational.

Comment: I thought a good way to make it unique was by using a hash. This seems alot easier. So If I want to add the frequency to a list I just increment an integer on the lists table?

Comment: That's it, you got it. You can have  other stats fields too such as: `create_date`, `update_date`, `last_used_date`, `frequency_of_use`, `likes`, etc...

Comment: Hash codes are not unique. If they were unique, there would never be any hash collisions. If you want a unique identifier for something, you need to guarantee it is unique. An auto-increment ID column does an excellent job of this for low-volume databases. For higher volumes, the common approach is to transition to a [universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: The only thing I am worried about is if an user inputs a new list there is no fast way of checking if this list is already in the database. I'd have to check every entry in the db for the item and then check every matched entry with the volume that is given. That's only for one item, imagine something like a list with more than 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many items you have. Assuming you use a good standard hash algorithm that gives you uniform distribution you only reach high collision chance when you get close to sqrt(number of possible ouputs). So a hash that gives you 32 bit values should be good for some thousands of entries. Switch to a 64 bit and you need to have some 4 billion entries to start seeing hash collisions.

A simple way to mitigate the collisions is to double check the values after a lookup if they don't match add some value to the hash sum and try again.

You can also go for higher bit count MD5 is commonly used to hash passwords. SHA can give you cryptographic guarantees. But likely both are overkill for your application.